# ImportError: No module named scitools.std,anaconda already installed

Tags: python, installation, scitools

I have installed anaconda and scitools with sudo.Where is the the problem?I got this:

```
from scitools.std import *
ImportError: No module named scitools.std
```

What should I check?

```
 echo "$PATH"
/home/milenko/anaconda/bin:/`
```

Comment: Check  if you have correctly installed `scitools`, aka if this path exists `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scitools`.

Comment: Is anaconda your default python check in the python path

Comment: No,I have just installed it 5 minitues ago,the default is usr/lib/python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `anaconda`,

You have to replace `apt-get` with `conda`.

Comment: May be problem is in directory structure,/home/m/anaconda and usr/lib/python?

Comment: Because if you use `apt-get`, the package usually will be installed in usr/lib/python